# Managing a large list of selectable, uncategorizable items

Tags: design-patterns, ux-field

[image]

I'm having a difficult time solving this problem and i'd appreciate any input.

Context: During checkout, a user has the option to pick one of 41 plans. Each plan has a corresponding value that the user (ideally) should be able to see alongside it.

Problem: 41 is a lot. Current implementation is a horizontal scrollable box, but that's proven to be annoying to a lot of our users.

These 41 plans are unique, so they can't be categorized or filtered. Any input would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: well, since there's no other information just use a dropdown, it's meant to be used exactly for this type of cases

Answer (score 0):

You do have something you can categorize on. The values. Or rather, the range of values.

Present a collection of buttons that let the user pick ranges of values (0 - 100, 101 - 200 etc.) and after choosing one the user is shown all the options that fall in that range.

The downside is that this adds a click to the process, but it makes it much easier for the user to find what they are looking for, which in my opinion is worth a click.